# How to combine has() and gt()

Tags: javascript, jquery

With jQuery 1.4.2, I can't figure out how to combine has() with :gt.  I'd like to select any `<ul>` which contains more than 3 `<li>`s, so here's what I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("ul.collapse:has(li:gt(2))")  
    .each( function() {  
       $(this).css("border", "solid red 1px");  
  });  
});
```

This does work with the 1.2.6 jQuery library, but not 1.3.2 or 1.4.2.  Why?

Comment: Using Kobi's code :

    $('ul').has('li:nth-child(3)').css('border', 'solid red 1px');

does work with the 1.4.2 library (though not 1.2.6).  

I would like to know why I'm seeing such a difference between the different versions of the jQuery library, if anyone knows.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello. I don't know why it didn't work. I saw a similar bug with `not`, but it was claimed to have been fixed. It is probably better if you edited the question or ask a new one; adding a comment doesn't bump it, so it won't get noticed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

```
$('ul').has('li:nth-child(3)').css('border', 'solid red 1px');
```

Working Example: http://jsbin.com/opape3

<sub>This selector didn't work for some reason: `$("ul.collapse:has(li:nth-child(3))")`</sub>

Comment: Reading the question again, you're probably asking why one worked and the other didn't.

Comment: Yes, thanks, the snippet using nth-child works for me.  (And seems simpler, too!)  Though, curiously, not with the 1.2.6 library; though I can see nth-child was added in 1.1.4.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$("ul").filter(function(){
    return $(this).find("li").length > 4;
}).each(function(){
    // your code   
});
```